# How to use ajax in VS code Extension API development

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to use `ajax` to retrieve data from a web service and display in   VS code Extension API development (Programmatic Language Features)

```
export function activate(ctx: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
    ...

    // Use ajax over here to retrieve data from a web service

    ctx.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider(
            GO_MODE, new GoDefinitionProvider()));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you can do there but it's javascript so, 
use Promise with Fetch inside and will work :) (?)